# Proving this function is a local homeomorphism. Is my proof correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, smooth-manifolds

I want to prove that $F\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{S}^1$, $\quad\theta\mapsto (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is a local homemorphism.

I reasoned as follows:

1) $F$ is clearly continuous.

2) For every $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ there is $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\theta\in (-\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi)$ or $\theta\in (k\pi,\pi+k\pi)$.

2.1) If $\theta\in (-\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi)$, than

$$F\colon (-\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi)\to \mathbb{S}^1\cap \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid (-1)^kx>0\}$$

is an homeomorphism, with inverse

$$G\colon \mathbb{S}^1\cap \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid (-1)^kx>0\}\to (-\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi), \quad(x,y)\to \arctan(y/x)+k\pi$$

2.2) If $\theta \in (k\pi,\pi+k\pi)$, then

$$F\colon (k\pi,\pi+k\pi)\to \mathbb{S}^1\cap \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid (-1)^ky>0\}$$  is an homeomorphism, with inverse

$$G\colon \mathbb{S}^1\cap \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid (-1)^ky>0\}\to (k\pi,\pi+k\pi), \quad(x,y)\to \operatorname{arccotan}(x/y)+k\pi$$

> 1) Am I right?
>
> 2) Is there a shorter and smarter proof? (But still elementary proof)
>
> 3) Is also true that all the above homeomorphisms are diffeomorphisms?

Comment: For another proof, on each interval $(k\pi,(k+1)\pi)$ the map $\theta \mapsto \cos(\theta)$ is a diffeomorphism onto $(-1,+1)$ whose inverse is plus or minus the arccosine function plus a constant, hence the composition $\theta \mapsto (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ is a diffeomorphism onto a semicircle. Similarly, on each interval $(k\frac{\pi}{2},(k+2)\frac{\pi}{2})$ the map $\theta \mapsto \sin(\theta)$ is a homeomorphism onto $(-1,+1)$, hence the composition $\theta \mapsto (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ is a diffeomorphism onto a semicircle.

Comment: I think I get the idea, but on $(k\frac{\pi}{2},(k+2)\frac{\pi}{2})$ the map $\theta \mapsto \sin (\theta)$ is not injective. For example for $k=0$ I have $(0,\pi)$ and the $\sin$ function has not inverse here.

Comment: I wrote that wrong, there should be a restriction "...on each interval $(k \frac{\pi}{2}, (k+2)\frac{\pi}{2})$ **such that $k$ is an odd integer**..."

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the three questions is yes. Let me show a alternative prove. Consider the map $f:\mathbb R \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ given by $f(t,r) = r(\cos(t),\sin(t))$.

Notice this map is smooth and surjective (because the map gives you polar coordinates). The jacobian of this map is the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(t)       & -r\sin(t) \\
  \sin(t)       & r\cos(t) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
whose determinant is $r>0$. Therefore, by the inverse function theorem this map is local diffeomorphism. The map you want is the restriction $F(t) = f(t,1)$, that will be local diffeomorphism too.

Comment: Thank-you for the answer. Can you elaborate why your $F$ is still a local diffeomorphism? And who is the codomain of your $F$? Have you shown that $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ is a local diffemorpshim, or $F:\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is a local diffeomorpshim?
Where is the reference to $S^1$ in your argument?

Comment: If $f:\mathbb R \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is local diffeomorphism then $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb S^1$ is also local diffeomorphism.